# clave de matriz indefinida en un select en PHP

Tags: php8

Buenas resulta que hice una consulta de una base de datos SQL y el resultado se muestra en un Select

```
      <form id="form1" name="form1" method=post">
      <?php
      require 'conexin.php';
    <label for="select">Obra</label>
    <select name="obras" id="obras">
    <option value="null" selected="selected" value="<?php echo $dota ?>">
    <option value="null">Seleccione Obra</option>
    <?php $statement = $pdo ->prepare("SELECT titulo_o,id_obra FROM Obras");
    $statement->execute();

    while( $row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo "<option value=\"$row[id_obra]\">$row[titulo_o]</option>";
    }
    ?>          
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
```

Al momento de querer guardar el valor seleccionado:

```
$valor = $_POST['obras'];
```

me aparece el siguiente error:

> Warning: Undefined array key "obras"

Comment: Pon todo el formulario, aqui solo aparece el SELECT y no sabemos si lo tienes dentro o fuera del **<form>** ni si lo mandas correctamente con POST o quizas es GET.

Comment: Ya esta el form completo

Comment: Bueno, supongo que es un error de tipeo en la pregunta, pero no has cerrado el interprete de PHP con `?>` después de `require 'conexin.php';`.  Aparte de eso, tiene buena pinta, aunque encuentro a faltar el `action=` en el `<form>`.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Si faltaba el Action que ya lo coloque, en si lo que trato de hacer es primero recuperar datos de una tabla que esta en SQLSERVER, para colocarlos en el un campo desplegable, lo cual hace bien, el problema resulta en que al momento de querer almacenar uno de esos datos que se seleccionar del campo desplegable en una variable para luego con esa variable hacer una consulta en otra tabla es que me aparece el error.